# Error while making a POST Request to acquire access token

Tags: sharepoint, postman, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-rest-api

I have been trying to get access token for REST API Calls for Sharepoint, through a post request in Postman. I double checked all the requirements and stil, I'm getting an error while making a POST Request.

Here are the following headers:

```
grant_type: authorization_code
client_id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
client_secret: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
code: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
redirect_uri: https://www.google.com/
resource: 00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000%2Fhp.sharepoint.com%40xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Here is the error which I got.

```
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "AADSTS7000015: Provided grant is invalid or malformed.\r\nTrace ID: fd7f7f6c-436b-49ae-ae3d-5bd79f513e01\r\nCorrelation ID: ef5f0448-3352-477e-bfdc-44453febeaad\r\nTimestamp: 2019-02-13 07:34:38Z",
"error_codes": [
    7000015
],
"timestamp": "2019-02-13 07:34:38Z",
"trace_id": "fd7f7f6c-436b-49ae-ae3d-5bd79f513e01",
"correlation_id": "ef5f0448-3352-477e-bfdc-44453febeaad"
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error when I try to request a new access_token with a refresh_token.

Comment: I did too, then I realized the refresh token is outdated. Once I requested a new access token the error was gone.